# How can view the Figma Telerik UI form on the blazor project?

Tags: telerik, blazor, blazor-webassembly, telerik-reporting, figma

Already created Telerik UI from by Figma. How can that plugging and view on blazor page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Figma but I think it is about styling so you probably have the CSS theme for the Telerik components from it. So, now you need the content - that is the actual form. Perhaps you just need a model with the desired fields and the TelerikForm to show them in.